# Login to put in frame ribbon (dx)

Tags: delphi

The login will be a panel containing two edit's, two labels and two buttons.
I would put a login frame where is circled in yellow in my ribbon. Any idea how to do it? I do not want to splash or ShowModal because of the publicity that has within the software.
Someone suggests something else?
[image: See...]

Another thing, how to remove the points green image?

Questioned in the forum of dx and talked to update the version, bad does not give right now. I'm using dxvcl14.1.2 ...

https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T205659

Comment: These are three questions, not one. And for question #2 and #3 I don't think you will get answers you like more than the ones from DevEx support.

Answer (score 3):

By adding two `TdxBarEdit`s, two Buttons and changing one BeginGroup property I got this:
[image: Screenshot]

I don't think you can make the login group right-aligned.

To add a `TdxBarEdit`, right click on the toolbar embedded into the tab group:
[image: Screenshot of adding a bar edit]

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the edit bar. Can you help me? Send me this project.

Comment: Could find. Thank you so much. What about removing those green dots of my image, can you? Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Sure: Upgrade your components like the DevEx guys told you. ;-)